# Dynamic segment with '/:slug' ...when the endpoint only accepts `/:id`

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have need of a dynamic route segment that displays `/:slug`, however, my endpoint only accepts `/:id` in the request url.

By default, ember will want to use the slug and build it into the request.  Somehow i would like that slug to serialize back into the correct id for the request only, while preserving the user friendly slug in the browser url.  It seems like a hack, but I am hoping there is a way?

Router

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('slug', { path: '/:slug_token' });
});
```

Slug Route

```
App.SlugRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log(params);
    return this.store.find('slug', params.slug_token);
  },
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { slug_token: model.get('slug_token') };
  }
});
```

Slug Link-to's

```
{{#each}}
  {{#link-to 'slug' this}}
    {{slug_name}}
  {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

And here is a [**(mostly) working jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/valaza/6/edit?html,js,output)  which demonstrates how ember data is trying to build the slug into the http request on a page refresh.

I assume that maybe this should be done in RESTSerializer, perhaps with a custom find method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already got access to the slugs, you can just filter on that collection.

```
App.SlugRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var slugs = this.modelFor('application');
    return slugs.filterBy('slug_token',params.slug_token).get('firstObject');
  },
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { slug_token: model.get('slug_token') };
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/quyonafimu/1/edit?html,js

If you don't, then slug_token would need to be unique, and you'd have to be able to call home and get the model based on that slug (using find by query if you wanted something like `slugs?slug_token=foo`.  Then you'd have to grab the first response, since find by query returns a collection.

Comment: Thank you! That was something i did not consider to just rely on the parent resource's model.  Not to throw an extra monkey on the pile.. but suppose the "single slug" endpoint returns more specific data than just the "slug list" endpoint.  That would indeed require a unique call to each endpoint.  Is it still a simple thing to accomplish?